# Spark SQLContext Query with header

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I'm using SQLContext to read in a CSV file like this:

```
val csvContents = sqlContext.read.sql("SELECT * FROM 
                  csv.`src/test/resources/afile.csv` WHERE firstcolumn=21")
```

But it's printing out the first column as `_c0` and including the header under it. How do I set the header and use the SQL query? I've seen this solution:

```
 val df = spark.read
         .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
         .csv("file.csv")
```

But this doesn't allow me to do the `SELECT` query with the `WHERE` clause. Is there a way to specify a CSV header and do a `SQL SELECT` query?

Comment: It can't recognize the column name from my where clause even though that name exists. I did:
```.select("*").where("col_id=22")```

But it gives an exception: 
```cannot resolve '`col_id`' given input columns: [col_id col_name```

Comment: Show the `src/test/resources/afile.csv`. Looks like the headers are not recognized by the CSV data source and you ended up with one long column name, e.g. `col_id col_name` (note the space between what is supposed to be column names).

Comment: BTW What Spark version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the header wasn't being parsed correctly. The CSV file was tab-delimited so I had to explicitly specify that:

```
val csvContents = sqlContext.read
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .option("header", "true")
        .csv(csvPath)
        .select("*")
        .where(s"col_id=22")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql query after creating a view from your dataframe. something like this.

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
  .csv("file.csv")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

val sqlDf = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstcolumn=21")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Initialize SparkSession
> 2. val fileDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",true).load("file.csv")
> 3. Post this you can have access to columns

```
     import spark.implicits._  
     fileDF.select($"columnName").where(conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

First If you are working with Spark 2.0 o later try to start using [SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html) instead of SparkContext then as another option if your number of columns is small I recommend you as a good practice

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._    
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("firstcolumn", StringType, true), 
  StructField("secondcolumn", IntegerType, true)
)

val df = spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  schema(schema).
  csv("file.csv")
```

So you can select your column with the correct name

```
val etl = df.select("firstcolumn").where("secondcolumn=0")
```

Comment: It can't recognize the column name from my where clause even though that name exists. I did:
```.select("*").where("col_id=22")```

But it gives an exception: 
```cannot resolve '`col_id`' given input columns: [col_id col_name```

Comment: Could you try `df.where(col("col_id") = 22)` or `df.where("col_id = 22")` also before everything you could run  `df.show` immediately after reading the CSV